# Xamarin - HttpClient, establish connection between iOS and server

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HTTPClient in Xamarin to call my server but sometimes the request takes a lot of time on IOS so I did check packet trace with `wireshark` and saw that the server doesn't reply. The Iphone sent a `SYN` but no `SYN ACK` from the server so when I using HTTPClient.PostAsync() and after X seconds, an exception is throw `The request timed out`. This issue appears sometimes but not all the time and on Android, HttpClient works perfectly.

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
try
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, json);
    .....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //exception
}
```

The HttpClient Implementation is on NSUrlSession.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

Any connection made with **NSUrlConnection**, **CFUrl** or **NSUrlSession** will use ATS by default in apps built for iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

Since ATS is enabled by default in apps built for iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), all connections using **NSUrlConnection**, **CFUrl** or **NSUrlSession** will be subject to ATS security requirements. If your connections do not meet these requirement, they will fail with an exception.

ATS will enforce the following requirements for all internet connections:

- All connection ciphers must be using forward secrecy. See the list of accepted ciphers below.
- The Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol must be version 1.2 or greater.
- At least a SHA256 fingerprint with either a 2048 bit or greater RSA key, or a 256 bit or greater Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key must be used for all certificates.

Again, since ATS is enabled by default in iOS 9, any attempt to make a connection that doesn't meet these requirements will result in an exception being thrown.

**In addition** , if using http in xamarin iOS , you can add follow content into `info.plist` :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><false/>  
</dict>
```

Reference : [App Transport Security in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats)